# Prove $f(z)=z^9+3z+1$ has 8 distinct zeroes in $A=\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid 1 < |z| < 2 \}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I know how to prove $f$ has 8 zeroes in $A$ using Rouche's theorem, but I still want to prove the zeroes are distinct.

Comment: If two roots are equal, it means it is a root with multiple order. So a root of $f'$. But the roots of $f'$ are not difficult to find...

Answer (score 1):

In order to show that a polynomial $f$ has no [multiple root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_%28mathematics%29#Multiplicity_of_a_root_of_a_polynomial), show that the greatest common divisor (GCD) of $f$ and $f'$ (the derivative) has degree $0$ (i.e. is a constant). In our case, $\gcd (f, f') = \gcd (z^9 + 3z +1, 9z^8 + 3)$ is indeed $1$. If you need more details, tell me in a comment.

Note that this method does not care about the set in which you look for roots, telling you that $f$ has no multiple root *anywhere*.

(Alternatively, you may want to show that the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Discriminant_of_a_polynomial) of $f$ is not $0$.)